# My slack app seems to fail in interaction

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack, slack-api

I'm new to slack app development. Following this page: https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity/enabling, I'm trying to create a simple interactive slack-app that

- is launched by a slash command
- can interact with users through a button.

I use AWS API-gateway and Lambda as backends. Lambda functions are written in Python 3.6.

I succeeded in creating a slash command, but failed in updating a message after pushed the button.

### Precise structure of my app

When I type the slash command `/test` in my slack channel, my app makes a post request to an API gateway (`https://xxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/test`) and a lambda function returns the following response with a button.

[image]

The lambda function is as follows:

```py
import json
import datetime


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try: 
        response = {
            "statusCode": 200, 
            "response_type": "in_channel",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "This is a section block with a button."
                    },
                },
                {
                    "type": "actions",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "button",
                            "text": {
                                "type": "plain_text",
                                "text": "Button", 
                                "emoji": True
                            },
                            "action_id": "test"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

        return response

    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

After the button pushed, my app sends a post request to another API gateway (`https://xxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/test2`) and another lambda function receives a request like follows

```
{  
   'type':'block_actions',
   'team':{  
      'id':'xxx',
      'domain':'xxx'
   },
   'user':{  
      'id':'xxx',
      'username':'xxx',
      'name':'xxx',
      'team_id':'xxx'
   },
   'api_app_id':'xxx',
   'token':'xxx',
   'container':{  
      'type':'message',
      'message_ts':'1564687520.001900',
      'channel_id':'xxx',
      'is_ephemeral':False
   },
   'trigger_id':'xxx.yyy.zzz',
   'channel':{  
      'id':'xxx',
      'name':'slack_app_test'
   },
   'message':{  
      'type':'message',
      'subtype':'bot_message',
      'text':"This content can't be displayed.",
      'ts':'1564687520.001900',
      'bot_id':'xxx',
      'blocks':[  
         {  
            'type':'section',
            'block_id':'ygl6',
            'text':{  
               'type':'mrkdwn',
               'text':"This is a section block with a button. {'token': 'xxx', 'team_id': 'xxx', 'team_domain': 'xxx', 'channel_id': 'xxx', 'channel_name': 'slack_app_test', 'user_id': 'xxx', 'user_name': 'mail', 'command': '/recommend', 'response_url': '<https://hooks.slack.com/commands/xxx/yyy/zzz>', 'trigger_id': 'xxx.yyy.zzz'}",
               'verbatim':False
            }
         },
         {  
            'type':'actions',
            'block_id':'jlzD',
            'elements':[  
               {  
                  'type':'button',
                  'action_id':'test',
                  'text':{  
                     'type':'plain_text',
                     'text':'Button',
                     'emoji':True
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   'response_url':'https://hooks.slack.com/actions/xxx/yyy/zzz',
   'actions':[  
      {  
         'action_id':'test',
         'block_id':'jlzD',
         'text':{  
            'type':'plain_text',
            'text':'Button',
            'emoji':True
         },
         'type':'button',
         'action_ts':'1564687524.157943'
      }
   ]
}
```

and try to make a response by the following lambda function:

```py
import json
import urllib.request


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        response_url = event.get("response_url", None)

        if response_url is not None:
            headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
            print("From slack. Response url: {}".format(response_url))

            response = json.dumps({
                "replace_original": True,
                "response_type": "in_channel",
                "text": "Success!"
            })

            request = urllib.request.Request(
                response_url, 
                data=response, 
                method="POST", 
                headers=headers
            )

        return None

    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

When I look at Cloudwatch logs of the lambda function above, the function seems to successfully send a message to my slack app.

### Problem

I expect that my app displays a message `Success!` after pushing the button, but no updates are shown (just showing a loading animation). Any ideas?

Comment: Slack wants you to send an acknowledge response with HTTP 200 for the button pressed request in addition to the response. You are returning `None` which I think might be the problem here. Try to respond with HTTP 200 instead. Source: https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity/enabling#ack